# Let's build a race car track!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

**Introduction**

My niece wants to make a race car track. She has wooden parts that fit together to form the track. Each part is square shaped and contains a different shape. I'll use the pipe drawing characters to illustrate:

- `│`: the road that goes vertically
- `─`: the road that goes horizontally
- `┌` `┐` `└` `┘`: the roads that turn in a direction
- `┼`: A bridge with an underpass

Curiously, there are no t-junction pieces.

Here's an example of a possible race car track:

```
┌─┐
│ │┌─┐
│ └┼─┘
└──┘
```

The rules for a valid race car track are as follows:

- There can't be any roads that go to nowhere.
- It must form a loop (and all the pieces must be part of the same loop).
- At the bridges / underpasses, you can't turn (so you have to go straight through them).

Unfortunately, the race car track pieces my niece and I have are limited. But we definitely want to use all of them in the track. Write a **program** that, given a list of what pieces are in our inventory, outputs a race car track that uses all of those pieces.

**Input Description**

We'd like the input to come in via STDIN, command line arguments, file reading, or a user input function (such as `raw_input` or `prompt`). The input is comma separated positive integers in the form

```
│,─,┌,┐,└,┘,┼
```

where each of those represent the amount of that particular piece we have. So for instance the input:

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

would mean that we had one of each piece.

**Output Description**

Output a race car track using the pipe drawing characters listed above. The race car track should use exactly the number of each piece specified in the input -- no more, and no less. There will be at least one valid race car track for every input.

**Example Inputs and Outputs**

Input: `3,5,2,2,2,2,1`

A possible output:

```
┌─┐
│ │┌─┐
│ └┼─┘
└──┘
```

Input: `0,0,1,4,4,1,3`

A possible output:

```
 ┌┐
 └┼┐
  └┼┐
   └┼┐
    └┘
```

Comment: Does it need to give the output? Or does it only theoretically need to give the output?

Comment: @Sumurai8 What do you mean by "theoretically" give the output? Do you mean a program that won't terminate for an extremely long time but will eventually give the output?

Comment: One would probably be able to create a field of n x n squares filled with the race pieces and empty squares, where you can generate permutations until you find something that is a race track. That would take forever for anything more than a few tiles.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Ah okay, I understand now. I would prefer that programs will  give an output before the heat death of the universe for the small value inputs I've shown in the challenge.

Comment: Your niece is not patient enough! :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Ruby 664 <s>671 677 687 701</s> (678 bytes)

```rb
_={│:[1,4],─:[2,8],┌:[4,8],┐:[4,2],└:[1,8],┘:[1,2],┼:[1,4,2,8]}
s=->a,l,b{l==[]&&a==[]?b:(l.product(l).any?{|q,r|q,r=q[0],r[0];(q[0]-r[0])**2+(q[1]-r[1])**2>a.size**2}?!0:(w,f=l.pop
w&&v=!a.size.times{|i|y=_[x=a[i]]
f&&y&[f]==[]||(k=l.select{|p,d|w!=p||y&[d]==[]}
(y-[f]).map{|d|z=[w[0]+(d<2?-1:(d&4)/4),w[1]+(d==2?-1:d>7?1:0)]
g=d<3?d*4:d/4
b[z]?_[b[z]]&[g]!=[]||v=0:k<<[z,g]}
v||r=s[a[0...i]+a[i+1..-1],k,b.merge({w=>x})]
return r if r)}))}
c=eval"[#{gets}]"
r=s[6.downto(0).map{|i|[_.keys[i]]*c[i]}.flatten,[[[0,0],nil]],{}]
h=j=k=l=0
r.map{|w,_|y,x=w
h>x&&h=x
j>y&&j=y
k<x&&k=x
l<y&&l=y}
s=(j..l).map{|_|' '*(k-h+1)}
r.map{|w,p|y,x=w
s[y-j][x-h]=p.to_s}
puts s
```

This is not the shortest program I could come up with, but I sacrificed some brevity for execution speed.

You can experiment with the program [here](http://ideone.com/L4TSYm). Note that ideone has an execution time limit, so for inputs consisting of more than about 12 pieces, the program will probably time out.

There's also a [test suite](http://ideone.com/6hCfFF) for the program. Note that the last two tests are disabled on ideone, due to the time limit mentioned above. To enable these tests, delete the `x_` prefix from their names.

The program finds a solution using Depth-first search; it places pieces one at a time and keeps tracks of loose ends. The search stops when there are no more loose (unconnected) ends and all pieces have been placed.

This is the ungolfed program:

```rb
N, W, S, E = 1, 2, 4, 8

# given a direction, find the opposite
def opposite (dir)
  dir < 3 ? dir * 4 : dir / 4
end

# given a set of coordinates and a direction,
# find the neighbor cell in that direction
def goto(from, dir)
  y, x = from

  dx = case dir
  when W then -1
  when E then 1
  else 0
  end

  dy = case dir
  when N then -1
  when S then 1
  else 0
  end

  [y+dy, x+dx]
end

CONNECTIONS = {
  ?│ => [N, S],
  ?─ => [W, E],
  ?┌ => [S, E],
  ?┐ => [S, W],
  ?└ => [N, E],
  ?┘ => [N, W],
  ?┼ => [N, S, W, E], 
}

BuildTrack =-> { 
  piece_types = CONNECTIONS.keys
  piece_counts = gets.split(?,).map &:to_i

  pieces = 6.downto(0).map{|i|piece_types[i]*piece_counts[i]}.join.chars

  def solve (available_pieces, loose_ends=[[[0,0],nil]], board={})

    return board if loose_ends==[] and available_pieces==[]

    # optimization to avoid pursuing expensive paths
    # which cannot yield a result.
    # This prunes about 90% of the search space
    c = loose_ends.map{ |c, _| c }
    not_enough_pieces = c.product(c).any? { |q, r| 
      ((q[0]-r[0])**2+(q[1]-r[1])**2) > available_pieces.size**2
    }
    return if not_enough_pieces

    position, connect_from = loose_ends.pop

    return unless position

    available_pieces.size.times do |i|
      piece = available_pieces[i]

      remaining_pieces = available_pieces[0...i] + available_pieces[i+1..-1]

      piece_not_connected_ok = connect_from && CONNECTIONS[piece] & [connect_from] == []
      next if piece_not_connected_ok

      new_loose_ends = loose_ends.select  { |pos, dir| 
        # remove loose ends that may have been 
        # fixed, now that we placed this piece
        position != pos || CONNECTIONS[piece] & [dir] == []
      }

      invalid_placement = false

      (CONNECTIONS[piece]-[connect_from]).map do |dir|
        new_pos = goto(position, dir)
        new_dir = opposite(dir)

        if board[new_pos]
          if CONNECTIONS[board[new_pos]] & [new_dir] != []
            # do nothing; already connected
          else
            # going towards an existing piece
            # which has no suitable connection
            invalid_placement = true
          end
        else
          new_loose_ends << [new_pos, new_dir]
        end
      end

      next if invalid_placement

      new_board = board.merge({position => piece})

      result = solve(remaining_pieces, new_loose_ends, new_board)
      return result if result
    end
    nil
  end

  def print_board board
    min_x = min_y = max_x = max_y = 0

    board.each do |position, _|
      y, x = position
      min_x = [min_x, x].min
      min_y = [min_y, y].min
      max_x = [max_x, x].max
      max_y = [max_y, y].max
    end

    str = (min_y..max_y).map{|_|
      ' ' * (max_x - min_x + 1)
    }

    board.each do |position, piece|
      y, x = position
      str[y-min_y][x-min_x] = piece
    end
    puts str
  end

  print_board(solve(pieces))
}
```